# Control number of files written to external Hive table in Spark SQL 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I'm writing to a partitioned, external hive table (format parquet) in Apache Spark 1.6.3. I want to write 1 file per partition (data is small, and I want to avoid the overhead of many small files). Let say the partition column is `date`. I can achieve this like that:

```
 df
  .coalesce(1)
  .write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("date")
  .insertInto(newTable)
```

But this makes me only 1 task for the `insertInto` stage, although many different file are created. So why isn't spark using multiple tasks to write the files instead of using 1 task to write all files.

On the other hand, If I omit the `coalesce(1)`, I get a huge amount of tiny files per hive partition.

So how can I speed-up the above code? Or more generally speaking, how can I control the number of files created when inserting into an Hive table (without using `coalesce(1)`)?

Comment: `coalesce(1)` is an anti-pattern in spark unless your data first in memory this you don't need spark to insert your data for you. On the other hand `repartition(numPartitions, $"date")`, with a number of partitions defined considering your data, will do good.

Comment: @eliasah so `numPartitions` should be equal to the number of different partitions my dataframe contains, i.e. unique values of `date`?

Comment: It's not necessary the unique values of date. If your data distribution is skewed that will probably hurt performance. I couldn't say without knowing your data.